# Positioning scopes side by side and vertically centered

Tags: tikz-pgf, positioning

I am trying to position a group of nodes side by side (in columnar alignment) and vertically centred, but fail to do so.

[image]

While the Operation box seems perfectly centred vertically w.r.t. the left nodes, the same cannot be said for the right nodes.

I can manually tweak the shift value every single time but I am looking for a better solution.

```latex
\begin{figure}[h!]
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
        op/.style={shape=rectangle, rounded corners, minimum width=4cm, minimum height=2cm, draw},
        tab/.style={shape=circle, minimum width=1.5cm, draw},
        hyp/.style={shape=circle, double, double distance=2pt, minimum width=1.5cm, draw},
    ]

\begin{scope}[local bounding box=ArgBox]
    \node[tab] (In1) {};
    \node[tab, below=of In1] (InN) {};
    \node at ($(In1)!0.5!(InN)$) {\vdots};
    \node[hyp, below=of InN] (Hyp1) {};
    \node[hyp, below=of Hyp1] (HypN) {};
    \node at ($(Hyp1)!0.5!(HypN)$) {\vdots};
\end{scope}

\begin{scope}[local bounding box=OpBox, shift={($(ArgBox.east)+(5cm,0)$)}]
    \node[op] (Op) {Operation};
\end{scope}

\begin{scope}[local bounding box=OutBox, shift={($(OpBox.east)+(5cm,0)$)}]
    \node[tab] (Out1) {};
    \node[tab, below=of Out1] (Out2) {};
    \node[tab, below=of Out2] (OutN) {};
    \node at ($(Out2)!0.5!(OutN)$) {\vdots};
\end{scope}

\draw[->] (In1) -- node [above, sloped] {arg \#1} (Op);
\draw[->] (InN) -- node [above, sloped] {arg \#N} (Op);
\draw[->] (Op) -- node [above, sloped] {out \#1} (Out1);
\draw[->] (Op) -- node [above, sloped] {out \#2} (Out2);
\draw[->] (Op) -- node [above, sloped] {out \#N} (OutN);
\draw[->] (Hyp1) -- node [above, sloped] {hyp \#1} (Op);
\draw[->] (HypN) -- node [above, sloped] {hyp \#N} (Op);
\end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{Caption}
    \label{fig:my_label}
\end{figure}
```

Thanks!

**Edit:** What I want is this, where the left nodes, the operation box, and the right nodes are always centered regardless of how many they are.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this:

[image]

With use of the `arrows.meta`, `calc`, `chains`, `positioning` and `quotes` the image code can be written as:

```
\documentclass[border=2mm,tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                calc, chains,
                positioning,
                quotes}
\usepackage{bm}
                
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance = 7mm and 22mm, 
  start chain = going below,
    op/.style = {shape=rectangle, rounded corners, minimum size=12mm, draw},
    vd/.style = {midway, text depth=0.25ex, text height=2.5ex,
                 inner ysep=0pt, node contents={$\bm{\vdots}$}},
   tab/.style = {shape=circle, minimum width=9mm, draw},
   hyp/.style = {tab, double},
       every edge/.style = {draw, -Straight Barb, shorten >=1pt, shorten <=1pt},
every edge quotes/.style = {auto, font=\footnotesize, sloped}
                    ]
% left in nodes
    \begin{scope}[nodes={on chain}]
\node[tab] (In1) {};
\node[tab] (InN) {};
\node[hyp] (Hyp1) {};
\node[hyp] (HypN) {};
    \end{scope}
\path   (In1) -- (InN)  node[vd] 
       (Hyp1) -- (HypN) node[vd]; 
% operation
\node[op, right=of $(In1)!0.5!(HypN)$] (Op) {Operation};
% right out nodes
    \begin{scope}[nodes={on chain}]
\node[tab, above right=of Op] (Out1) {};
\node[tab] (Out2) {};
\node[tab] (OutN) {};
\end{scope}
\path   (Out2) -- (OutN) node[vd];
% arrows
\draw   (In1) edge ["arg \#1"]  (Op)
        (InN) edge ["arg \#N"]  (Op)
        (Op)  edge ["out \#1"]  (Out1)
        (Op)  edge ["out \#2"]  (Out2)
        (Op)  edge ["out \#N"]  (OutN)
        (Hyp1) edge ["hyp \#1"] (Op)
        (HypN) edge ["hyp \#N"] (Op);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**Addendum:**
More general, "semi-automatic"  solution :). It require:

- node vertical distance had to be equal as diameters of `tab`  nodes (command `\vnd`)
- for horizontal distance had to be defined horizontal length as command ´(`\hnd`
- defined number of output nodes (`\NUM`)
- to chain of the right output nodes should be inserted `\NUM` nodes
- for calculation of position for the first node in the right chain is defined macro `\K`. By it is this position calculated as `above right=\K*\vnd and \hnd of Op.east`
- right chain is vertical shit for amount calculated as `(<tab minimum size>-<(inserted square minimum size)/2>`

MWE for 7 output nodes:

```
\documentclass[border=2mm,tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                calc, chains,
                positioning,
                quotes}
\usepackage{bm}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance = \vnd and \hnd,
  start chain = going below,
    op/.style = {shape=rectangle, rounded corners, 
                 minimum size=12mm, 
                 draw},
    vd/.style = {midway, text depth=0.25*\vnd, text height=0.75*\vnd,
                 inner ysep=0pt, node contents={$\bm{\vdots}$}},
   tab/.style = {shape=circle, 
                 minimum size=\vnd, inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt, draw},
   hyp/.style = {tab, double},
       every edge/.style = {draw, -Straight Barb, shorten >=1pt, shorten <=1pt},
every edge quotes/.style = {auto, font=\footnotesize, inner sep=2pt, sloped}
                    ]
\def\vnd{ 6 mm} % minimum size is 6mm
\def\hnd{21 mm}
\def\NUM{7}     % number of output nodes
\pgfmathsetmacro{\K}{0.5*int(2*\NUM+1)-2} 

% left input nodes
    \begin{scope}[nodes={on chain}]
\node[tab] (In1) {};
\node[tab] (InN) {};
\node[hyp] (Hyp1) {};
\node[hyp] (HypN) {};
    \end{scope}
\path   (In1) -- (InN)  node[vd]
       (Hyp1) -- (HypN) node[vd];
% operation
\node[op, right=of $(In1.east)!0.5!(HypN.east)$] (Op) {Operation};
% right output nodes, 
    \begin{scope}[nodes={yshift=0.29289 mm, on chain}]
\node[tab, above right=\K*\vnd and \hnd of Op.east] (Out1) {};
\node[tab] (Out2) {};
\node[tab] (OutN) {};
\node[hyp] (Hyp1) {};
\node[hyp]  (Hyp2) {};
\node[tab]  (OutM) {};
\node[hyp]  (Hyp4) {};
    \end{scope}
\path (Out2) -- (OutN)  node[vd];
% arrows
\draw   (In1) edge ["arg \#1"]  (Op)
        (InN) edge ["arg \#N"]  (Op)
       (HypN) edge ["hyp \#N"]  (Op)
        (Op)  edge ["out \#1"]  (Out1)
        (Op)  edge ["out \#2"]  (Out2)
        (Op)  edge ["out \#N"]  (OutN)
        (Op)  edge ["hyp \#1"]   (Hyp1)
        (Op) edge ["hyp \#1"]   (Hyp4)
        ;
 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Result for \NUM=3 is the same as at first answer, for \num=4 is

[image]

and for \NUM=7 is

[image]

Comment: This does not work when I add the fourth node to the right (out). Isn't there a way to tell tikz to place the out scope to the right of op, while centering vertically?

Comment: In your question  was shown only three node on the right side and not mentioned that it should work for any number of nodes. Sorry.

Comment: No worries, thank you for your time anyway!

Comment: @BoraM.Alper, late evening (GMT) I will return to your question and try to find more general solution. Problem which I need to solve, is how determine position of the top output node :-)

Comment: @BoraM.Alper, now is added new solution which enable to add any number of nodes on the right side of images on the way, that they are vertically centered do `Operation` node.

Comment: Thank you so much! You have been incredibly helpful. =)